# No Such Method Error when creating JUnit test

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit, netbeans6.5

I've tried figuring out this problem for the last 2 days with no luck.  I'm simply trying to create an annotation based JUnit test using the spring framework along with hibernate.

My IDE is netbeans 6.5 and I'm using hibernate 3, spring 2.5.5 and JUnit 4.4.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Testcase: testFindContacts(com.mycontacts.data.dao.MyContactHibernateDaoTransactionTest):        Caused an ERROR
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:203)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:93)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:130)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [shared-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:42)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:199)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
```

Comment: It appears to be a configuration problem (class path) with netbeans 6.5.  I copied the project over to eclipse and it works just fine.

Comment: I'm getting this ERROR even if in Eclipse I tried with 1.5/3.1/4.0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` always indicates that the version of a class that was on your compiler's classpath is different from the version of the class that is on your runtime classpath (had the method been missing at compile-time, the compile would have failed.)

In this case, you had a different version of `org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter` on your classpath at compile time than is on your runtime classpath.

Comment: what do you mean by "version is different" ? is it missing method in the runtime class, or whatever change in the runtime class ? I suppose that compiling something with a class, that then gets a new static field (irrelevant thing) and is used in runtime, doesn't throw this error right ?

Comment: just to say it does not 'always' indicate that it's a different version but may also be that the same version is loaded twice. I had this problem the other day. To further narrow down where the problem comes from start your vm with `-class:verbose` which displays all classes loaded and from where

Comment: It's `-verbose:class`

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.parseRequest` getting this error. The jar that I use is `commons.fileupload1.2.1.jar` Does the version in this is what you mention?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you have different versions of your ClassWriter class at runtime than compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are picking up an incorrect version of asm.jar somewhere in the classpath you are using for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error using Spring 2.5 with Hibernate on NetBeans 6.5.  One way I resolved the issue was downloading Spring 3.0 M2 and creating a NetBeans library I called Spring_3 using the jars from the distro. This library also had to include the antlr-runtime-3.0.jar.

See:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=65324

-Leo

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my suggestion for anyone who comes across this JUnit Testing for Android; none of the above worked for me and this was a simple fix:

In `Eclipse>>project properties>>Android>>` make sure that the project you are testing is referenced under Library. 'is library' can remain unchecked