# What's this Spring error and how to fix it

Tags: eclipse, spring

```
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:50 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer property decoder has been initialized.
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:testispring' did not find a matching property.
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Aineistopankki01' did not find a matching property.
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1537 ms
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: SpringSource tc Server/6.0.20.C
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:52 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/administrator/springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.C/wtpwebapps/Aineistopankki01/WEB-INF/lib/javax.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [/home/administrator/springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.C/wtpwebapps/Aineistopankki01/]
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'database' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:540)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:741)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:587)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
 at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:228)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:170)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.java:173)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
 ... 27 more
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/Aineistopankki01] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive insight.war
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Sep 17 15:32:54 EEST 2010]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/mvc-config.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/app-config-tomcat.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/springsource/insight/dashboard/app-config-base.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10bcc8f4: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,localeResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver#0,tilesConfigurer,jsonView,traces/window/json,traces/trace/json,resources/resource/leadingAverage/json,resources/resource/histogram/json,resources/resources/json,traces/last/xstream,freemarkerConfig,tracesController,traceRepoInterceptAttacher,applicationsController,homeController,sorter,configController,resourcesController,resourceSummaryFactory,executorTraceCreator,insightVersionNumber,insightApplication,memoryMetricDataRepo,staticMetricRepo,memoryResourceRepoImpl,memoryTraceRepo,traceFilterListFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,conversionService,endPointAnalysisTraceListener,traceListenerList,traceCreatingExecutor,com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.YamlInsightConfigFactoryBean#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.YamlInsightConfigFactoryBean - Reading Spring Insight config: /home/administrator/springsource/tc-server-6.0.20.C/conf/spring-insight.yml
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/windows/{start}/{end:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/lastTraces/{application}/{end}/{count}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/lastTraces/{application}/{end}/{count}.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/lastTraces/{application}/{end}/{count}/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/frames/{frameId}/operation] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/frames/{frameId}/operation.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/traces/{traceId}/frames/{frameId}/operation/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.traces.TracesController@5a81b83c]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/traces/{application:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints/{application:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/applications/endpoints/{application}/{resource:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.applications.ApplicationsController@5c8032df]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Root mapping to handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.HomeController@4e26d560]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@31672113]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@31672113]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@31672113]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/config/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.config.ConfigController@31672113]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/histogram] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/histogram.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/histogram/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/leadingAverage] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/leadingAverage.*] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/{start}/{end}/leadingAverage/] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/{application}/{resource}/traces/{start}/{end}/{min}/{max:.*}] onto handler [com.springsource.insight.dashboard.resources.ResourcesController@7d0e6cbd]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer - TilesConfigurer: adding definitions [/WEB-INF/**/tiles*.xml]
WARN : org.apache.tiles.context.ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory - Cannot find TilesRequestContextFactory class org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer - ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization completed in 4082 ms
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:58 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 17, 2010 3:32:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7191 ms
```

Comment: formatted. i think its the issue of version conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You have an incompatibility between the version of ASM required by Hibernate (asm-1.5.3.jar) and the one required by Spring. But, actually, I wonder why you have asm-2.2.3.jar on your classpath (ASM is bundled in spring.jar and spring-core.jar to avoid such problems AFAIK). See [HHH-2222](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2222).

from   [Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv)

check

[No Such Method Error when creating JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425039/no-such-method-error-when-creating-junit-test)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/217661/ORM/java/java-lang-NoSuchMethodError

[Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432471/error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-objectweb-asm-classwriter-initiv)

Comment: So which jar should be removed?

Comment: which version of asm jar you are using and which app server you are using ?