# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while uploading file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I am developing an application which has an image upload module. I have written the following code to get multipart form data.

> List items = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);

I am using `commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar` for this purpose. When I am deploying my build on `jboss-5.1.0.GA` server, it gives an error while uploading any file. The error is as follows:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)Ljava/util/List;
>           at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
>           at com.bworld.action.UploadSubscriptionImage.processRequest(UploadSubscriptionImage.java:46)
>           at com.bworld.action.UploadSubscriptionImage.doPost(UploadSubscriptionImage.java:145)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Can any one please tell me how to recover from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong jar.  Your classpath is referencing something different than what you think it is.  Check your Jboss lib and classpath for jars with a similar name, but different versions.  Then do a full clean + build cycle, delete jboss tmp directory, and do a clean + publish on the server.  Here is another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425039/no-such-method-error-when-creating-junit-test)

Answer (score 1):

Your commons file-upload jar is missing from your WEB-INF/lib folder OR it is already shipped by JBoss and you should not duplicate it in WEB-INF/lib

Related: http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=866

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but my answer might help someone,
this can cause because of few reason

1. commons file-upload jar might be missing in the your WEB-INF/lib folder as Bonzho mentioned
2. commons file-upload is shipped with latest tomcat and jboss servers so you need not to use that jar externally in your project. but lets say you have used it, then you can try removing it from the class path and do a clean build, that should most probably work
3. but sometimes you might still get the error saying java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: that can be happen because of eclipse not showing an error for the older imports that came from the commons-fileupload jar you used so go through the classes of your project and make sure that 
   import statement is either  `import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.*` or `import org.apache.commons.fileupload*` not both

It is always a good practice to use a pom.

Answer (score 0):

use commons-fileupload 1.3.3 version. I used and solved this